# How to disable retry in spring boot without removing it?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-retry

i have 2 methods in class:

```
@Retryable(maxAttemptsExpression="${retry.maxAttempts}", backoff=@Backoff(delayExpression = "${retry.delay}", multiplierExpression = "${retry.multiplier}"))
public void foo() {
/**some body**/
}

@Recover
public void fooRecover() {
/**some body**/
}
```

In some cases i need to disable retrying, but maxAttempts can't be equals zero, so i can't simply do it. So how to correctly disable retrying in some cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Retryable annotation has a property `exceptionExpression` where you can specify SpEL expression that evaluates to true or false.

```
/**
 * Specify an expression to be evaluated after the
 * {@code SimpleRetryPolicy.canRetry()} returns true - can be used to conditionally
 * suppress the retry. Only invoked after an exception is thrown. The root object for
 * the evaluation is the last {@code Throwable}. Other beans in the context can be
 * referenced. For example: <pre class=code>
 *  {@code "message.contains('you can retry this')"}.
 * </pre> and <pre class=code>
 *  {@code "@someBean.shouldRetry(#root)"}.
 * </pre>
 * @return the expression.
 * @since 1.2
 */
String exceptionExpression() default "";
```

So if you want to disable retry you can inject boolean string parameter with value "false"

```java
@Retryable(exceptionExpression = "${retry.shouldRetry}", ...other stuff...)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problems are on the conditions. In which case you want to retry and which you want to stop?

So then you can define the value=?Exception.class in the annotation.

For example:

```
@Retryable(value=MUST_RETRY_EXCEPTION.class)
public void foo() {

    if (condition) {
        throw new MUST_RETRY_EXCEPTION(...);
    }

    if (condition2) {
        throw new NO_RETRY_EXCEPTION(...);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove @Retryable, you simply don't want what code dose then remove it

Comment: in some cases @Retryable is necessary in others it is not. So just removing it's not a solution

Comment: in the case where you client application do not require retry, retry logic must be removed from client(consumer) then, this should remain retryable alwaysthen